# May i use this flush mount conduit clamp side mount horizontally?

Tags: electrical

Is it against nec code, to use this clamp [image: flange mount conduit clamp-side mount]the way the picture shows it for my emt 1/2" conduit to make a T connection?  The hole would be against the 2/6 vertically with a screw into it and fits perfectly regardless that this was made for fitting between a beam.  There isnt another ceiling hanging clamp besides garvin industry which i could put a shim behind it to make the T clamp connection to hold the 1/2" emt hanging conduit? A third simple solution since my conduit is less than five feet and has an outlet at both ends...Could i use just one regular clamp that is within 3 ft of both. Sorry for being a little paranoid...just want to clarify with the experts. Appreciate the insights. Thank u larry

Answer (score 2):

You could try those like that if you want.

We use pipe hangers Called "Minnies" in the trade since a company called Minerallac makes them.

They look like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009ZVP4XS).

The hanger you show is a Caddy Clip and is made to drive on to the edge of a steel bar joist. It will work but they are actually kind of expensive for the same purpose.

You can use the Minnies to run parallel or perpendicular to a floor joist.

And yes if your conduit is less then six feet one in the middle will satisfy Code.

Good luck!

Comment: Of course the amazon prime item you linked as an example of what it looks like is not the right price 12.83 / 5 = 2.54 each.  Depending where'd its bought (besides amazon prime) a 1/2" Minnie should cost .40 to .60 each.

Comment: I was just going to say that.  Some things on Amazon Prime are outrageously overpriced.  Free shipping isn't free. (Even though I seem to remember paying $89/year for it!)

Comment: True the link was to show the item not an example of a good price. I would buy them at the electrical wholesale house in quantity. Or a local hardware or box store if you just need a couple.

Comment: I called out the amazon pricing primarily because you stated they were less expensive than caddy OP's caddy clip-- but at the amazon price the caddy may actually win the price war.